# Safely use a bare light socket

Tags: electrical, lighting, safety

I've got a box of sockets like this:

[image: light socket]

I was planning to mount a few of these on the ceiling, but am wondering about safety since the hot wire is essentially exposed, and would be very close to one's fingers when changing a bulb. I stopped at the hardware store and saw sockets just like these, except they had cardboard around the upper portion. Would I be ok wrapping electrical tape around the upper portion, or does anyone have better ideas? I also thought about wrapping tape on it then putting a cover [like this](http://www.colorcord.com/collections/socket-covers/products/industrial-metal-socket-cover) over it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right to be concerned about safety. Attempting to use the sockets as they are is a  hazard, the exposed conductors are an electrical and safety concern. What you have is a replacement part for repairing a damaged fixture.

Answer (score 4):

As @mikes said, this is a replacement part - NOT a complete fixture. Rather than cobbling up some mess of electrical tape, just buy a plain porcelain (or plastic, though oddly the porcelain are often cheaper, and I assume the reason you are contemplating this at all is to keep costs down) lampholder that is designed for the job, and don't create an electrical and fire hazard.

[image] [image]

If you want a pendant type, these are also inexpensive and safely insulated. For a little more, they can be dressed up with a shade or a frosted glass disk.

[image]

Comment: True, I am trying to keep costs down, but I'm also going for a more industrial look in my shop, so I was avoiding the standard ceramic sockets. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @TrevorHartman - The porcelain light socket fixtures are about as industrial / steam punk as they come.

Comment: Black electrical tape isn't steampunk, any late Victorian/Edwardian style steampunk electrics will be using lots of glass, ceramic and hard rubber for insulation. Go for safe.

Comment: Workshop type shop or retail type shop?

Comment: Funny enough, the link posted for the metal cover is designed to fit the ceramic shroud posed in this link. So if you are looking for an industrial look, that would be the way to go.

Comment: Also, Stay away from insulation tape on the socket, IF someone uses incandescent bulbs, the tape could start to melt if it gets too hot.

Comment: @Ecnerwal work shop: woodworking, electronics (Arduino/low voltage) projects, general hacking space

Comment: To be clear, I'm not going for Steampunk - more of a modern industrial look - lots of metal. I think the ceramic pendant sockets with the metal socket covers will work great. Now if I can find where to buy ceramic sockets... @Ecnerwal where did you find the pendant photo? I must be searching for the wrong thing because I can't find any on ebay.

Comment: @TrevorHartman porcelain pendant light socket, images, looking for what I was looking for worked for me. I think the picture came from 1000 bulbs - ebay is unlikely to be the best place to find these, I think. It's a standard, current production Leviton part, street price around $2, sites that think you are a fool price upwards of $6. Drill a hole in a cheap stainless salad bowl and get more metal.